# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.xxx.Model.Users.getName()' on a null object

Tags: android-studio

txtFullName.setText(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName());

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear mention user problem by providing the code to solve your issue.